# jQuery match first letter in a string and wrap with span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace

I'm trying to get the first *letter* in a paragraph and wrap it with a `<span>` tag. Notice I said letter and not character, as I'm dealing with messy markup that often has blank spaces.

**Existing markup** (which I can't edit):

```
<p>  Actual text starts after a few blank spaces.</p>
```

**Desired result:**

```
<p>  <span class="big-cap">A</span>ctual text starts after a few blank spaces.</p>
```

How do I ignore anything but `/[a-zA-Z]/` ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What should happen in the case of the following html: `<p> 15346  Actual text starts after a few blank spaces, and numbers.</p>`, should the `A` still be wrapped, or should there be no wrapping?

Comment: No wrapping should occur, though the scenario you're describing is very unlikely to happen. Good point though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('p').html(function (i, html)
{
    return html.replace(/^[^a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z])/g, '<span class="big-cap">$1</span>');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/t3DNY/

Comment: [Doesn't seem to work, if non-alpha characters appear first](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/t3DNY/2/). My assumption was that, should this occur, he'd still want the `A` wrapped in a span, rather than nothing wrapped in a span...my assumption may, of course, be invalid. =/

Comment: @David I just edited the regexp but you're still basically right. The question is (in your example) should `1` or `A` be wrapped? Based on the OP, I understand the answer to be `A`, not `1`. Easy enough to tweak, though.

Comment: Well, I think it's pretty clear from the question that the `1` should (at least 'probably') not be wrapped (it's non A-Z, after all), but is instead whether there should be *any* wrapping, or not...perhaps the OP could provide some clarity?

Comment: This works great, exactly what I needed. To further clarify, the purpose is to wrap the first visible letter for CSS styling purposes.

Comment: Improvements to the regular expression: `[a-zA-Z]` is the same as `[A-z]`. If you want to ignore white space use `\s`. Drop the `g` flag because you only care about the first match. This is what it then looks like: `/^\s*([A-z])/`.

Comment: As noted in another answer, this solution breaks if child HTML tags such as IMG are first: http://jsfiddle.net/g6dbssst/

Answer (score 4):

I would vote against using JS for this task. It'll make your page slower and also it's a bad practice to use JS for presentation purposes.

Instead I can suggest using `:first-letter` pseudo-class to assign additional styles to the first letter in paragraph. Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/e4XY2/. It should work in all modern browsers except IE7.

Comment: Is IE7 still considered "modern" ?

Comment: Ok, it isn't modern but it's still widely used.

Comment: I have to support IE7 so this isn't an option. The other disadvantage of :first-letter is that it's interpreted slightly differently across browsers, whereas the span trick is much easier to style.

Comment: `:first-letter` is very difficult to style across browser. Give up and use a span.

Comment: The new "initial-letter" property is still not supported by any browsers, so wrapping the first letter is still necessary to use something such as the dropcap.js polyfill.

Answer (score 4):

Matt Ball's solution is good but if you paragraph has and image or markup or quotes the regex will not just fail but break the html
for instance

```
<p><strong>Important</strong></p>
    or
<p>"Important"</p>
```

You can avoid breaking the html in these cases by adding "'< to the exuded initial characters.  Though in this case there will be no span wrapped on the first character.

```
 return html.replace(/^[^a-zA-Z'"<]*([a-zA-Z])/g, '<span class="big-cap">$1</span>');
```

I think Optimally you may wish to wrap the first character after a ' or " 
I would however consider it best to not wrap the character if it was already in markup, but that probably requires a second replace trial.

Comment: Any way to have it work for ANY character... as long as it's not an HTML element as the first character?

Answer (score 1):

I do not seem to have permission to reply to an answer so forgive me for doing it like this. The answer given by Matt Ball will not work if the P contains another element as first child. Go to the fiddle and add a IMG (very common) as first child of the P and the I from Img will turn into a drop cap.

Answer (score -1):

If you use the x parameter (not sure if it's supported in jQuery), you can have the script ignore whitespace in the pattern. Then use something like this:

```
/^([a-zA-Z]).*$/
```

You know what format your first character should be, and it should grab only that character into a group. If you could have other characters other than whitespace before your first letter, maybe something like this:

```
/.*?([a-zA-Z]).*/
```

Conditionally catch other characters first, and then capture the first letter into a group, which you could then wrap around a span tag.