# span first character with query

Tags: jquery

inspired by:
[jQuery match first letter in a string and wrap with span tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720220/jquery-match-first-letter-in-a-string-and-wrap-with-span-tag/16345377#16345377)

I try to span the first character of each div that is of class split.
Atm i have this:

```
$(".split").each(function(index) {

    $(this).html(function (i, html) {   
        console.log(html);
        return html.replace(/^[^a-zA-Z'"<]*([a-zA-Z])/g, '<span class="big-cap">$1</span>');
    });

});
```

It log's stuff like this:

```
<p>De laatste eeuwen veranderen letters meer in details en niet meer in drastische vorm, de Garamond is al meer dan 400 jaar oud en wordt nog steeds gebruikt dus je zou kunnen zeggen dat de lettervorm hoe die nu is min of meer af is.</p>
```

So i figured the `<p>` is the problem.

So how can i get past the first paragraph element?
So if i log `html` it doesn't log the `<p>`.

Remember, i only want to span the first character of each div of class `split`.

Comment: Is the `p` tag *always* the first thing in the `.split` element? If so you could select that instead. If not, you will have to use `contents()` and recursively loop through each element to get the first textNode, and get the first character. It is not straightforward :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to wrap the first character of an element that has no child :

```
$(".split").each(function(index) {
  $(':not(:has(*))', this).html(function (i, html) {   
        return html.replace(/^[^a-zA-Z'"<]*([a-zA-Z])/g, '<span class="big-cap">$1</span>');
    });
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/pibuviwa/1/edit)

As I'm not sure of your goal, maybe you want `':not(:has(*)):eq(0)'` if you don't want to change all paragraphs but only the first one.

Comment: thanks. I needed it with the `eq(0)`. Works like a champ!
What does the `:not(:has(*))` do? I understand `not` and i understand `has` but i don't get that line.

Comment: @clankill3r It's getting elements that are *not* (`:not`) *having* (`:has`) (i.e. containing) any element (`*`).

Comment: Ah so if i understand correct, no `<p>` `<br/>` or any other html element.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider jQuery [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-functionindex--text) instead of html to get the text without html.

But then when adding the span and replacing the html of your element, the `<p>` will be gone. If you can't afford that, then your other option is that you can go through the `p` inside your `.split` elements by using `$('p', '.split').each( ... )` if there is only one `<p>` inside.